# Trouble by including a static library in makefile

Tags: c, makefile, static-libraries

I have some troubles by including a static library in our handwritten makefile.

We want include the lib: STL_lib.a which is in the directory: Library/STM32_Safety_STL/Lib
So I wrote this line into the makefile:

```
...
LDFLAGS_END += -Wl,--gc-sections -static -Wl,--start-group -lc -lm -lSTL_Lib -Wl,--end-group --specs=nosys.specs
...
LDLIBS := Library/STM32_Safety_STL/Lib
...
$$(BUILD_DIR)/$1.elf : $$(OBJECTS) | $$(BUILD_DIR)
@echo ' '
$$(LD) \
    $$(DEFS) \
    -T $$(LDSCRIPTS) \
    -L $$(LDLIBS) \
    $$(LDFLAGS) \
    $$(LDFLAGS_END) \
    $$(MAP_FILE) \
    -o $$(@) $$(OBJECTS)
...
```

When I call the makefile, I get this error:

> arm-none-eabi-gcc.exe  -DSTM32L4R5xx -DUSE_HAL_DRIVER -DDEBUG -T HAL/CubeMX/STM32L4R5VGTX_FLASH.ld -L Library/STM32_Safety_STL/Lib -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mthumb -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -Wl,--gc-sections -static -Wl,--start-group -lc -lm -lSTL_Lib -Wl,--end-group --specs=nosys.specs -Wl,-Map="./Develop/Debug/MCU1_Develop.map" -o ./Develop/Debug/MCU1_Develop.elf
> c:\st\stm32cubeide_1.8.0\stm32cubeide\plugins\com.st.stm32cube.ide.mcu.externaltools.gnu-tools-for-stm32.9-2020-q2-update.win32_2.0.0.202105311346\tools\arm-none-eabi\bin\ld.exe: cannot find -lSTL_Lib
> collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Can anyone give me a hint? :)
Thank you

Comment: The doubled-up dollar signs surprise me.  It appears that the `libSTL_Lib.a` library is not named like that or is not where you think it is.

Comment: Thank you for your response.
Yes, the library is not named like libSTL_Lib.a, it is named STL_Lib.a (the library is an safety lib from STM). But I´ve tried with renaming it to libSTL_Lib.a... That doesn't help ether

Comment: I'm quite sure that the content here is actually part of a `define` which is used later via `eval` and `call` to generate rules.  The cut and paste simply didn't include the entire thing.

Comment: I´ve looked in the documentation, unfortunately there is no define, which must be set. :)

Answer (score 1):

The key part of that error message is:

> cannot find -lSTL_Lib

Since you have specified static linking, `-lSTL_Lib` instructs the linker to search for a file named `libSTL_Lib.a` in the library search path and link it.  If the library of interest is indeed named as you describe:

> We want include the lib: STL_lib.a which is in the directory: Library/STM32_Safety_STL/Lib

... then you cannot designate it to the linker via a standard `-l` option.  The form of the name is incorrect for that.

There is more than one alternative, but perhaps simplest would be to just give a full path to the library instead: `Library/STM32_Safety_STL/Lib/STL_lib.a`.  In that case, you might not need the `-L Library/STM32_Safety_STL/Lib` option.

Comment: I changed the LDLIBS Flag to:
LDLIBS := Library/STM32_Safety_STL/Lib/STL_lib.a
and removed all -L and -l flags. Unfortunately this error appers:
c:\st\stm32cubeide_1.8.0\stm32cubeide\plugins\com.st.stm32cube.ide.mcu.externaltools.gnu-tools-for-stm32.9-2020-q2-update.win32_2.0.0.202105311346\tools\arm-none-eabi\bin\ld.exe: ./Develop/Debug/obj/HAL/Csp/CspStl.o: in function `CspStl_Init':
./Develop/HAL/Csp/CspStl.c:104: undefined reference to `STL_SCH_Init'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:342: ./Develop/Debug/MCU1_Develop.elf] Error 1

Comment: That would be a separate issue, @bastian7032, but likely it is related to the order of the command-line arguments.  Especially for static linking, you need to order the objects being linked together so that any unresolved symbols referenced by each object being linked are resolved by an object named later on the link command line.

Comment: Uff okay... what did i here wrong?
In my opinion it looks like that the linker cannot open the STL_Lib.a

Comment: @bastian7032, if the linker could not open a file specified on the command line, then that is what it would report.  Again, the *order* of elements on the link command line matters.  I don't know all the dependencies of the various objects involved, but from what you describe, `STL_lib.a` is presently appearing too early in the command.  It almost surely should go *after* `$$(OBJECTS)`.  So too `-lm`, and if it's actually necessary, `-lc`.

Comment: thank you very much. I have solved the problem by using your tip with the order :)